# Design-Time Population of ListBox with Sample Data in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, blend, design-time

I have a view (usercontrol) that contains a listbox.
At runtime the listbox will be populated with instances of another view (also a usercontrol).
How can I populate the listbox in design-time (in Blend and Cider) with sample views that are themselves populated with sample data?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834283/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-wpf-is-currently-executing-in-design-mode-or-not

Comment: It's not the same question. I'm trying to find a design-time way to populate a listbox with sample data without it appearing in runtime.

Answer (score 5):

Using VS2010 you can use [Design-Time attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602277%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (works for both SL and WPF). I usually have a mock data-source anyway so it's just a matter of:

- Adding the namespace declaration

  `xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"`
- Adding the mock data context to window/control resources

  ```
  <UserControl.Resources>
      <ViewModels:MockXViewModel x:Key="DesignViewModel"/>
  </UserControl.Resources>
  ```
- Setting design-time data context

  ```
  <Grid d:DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource DesignViewModel}}"> ...
  ```

Works well enough.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the **BookLibrary** sample application of the [**WPF Application Framework (WAF)**](http://waf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Downloads&referringTitle=Home) interesting. It uses the new design-time support of Visual Studio 2010 and Expression Blend 4. Please download the .Net4 version of WAF.