# Question about ViewModel Management (DesignTime Vs Run Time)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a fairly basic WPF UI whereby user requests cause a new tab to open in my TabControl.  The TabControl is bound to an `ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>`

I add ViewModel instances to this collection, and the corresponding tab's content is displayed based on templates like this:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:UserUploadsViewModel}">
        <userControls:UserUploads />
    </DataTemplate>
```

Now let's say that inside of the UserUploads control I'd like to wire up a ViewModel in XAML to help with the designing, like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class=".....UserUploads"
   .....
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocater},
                  Path=UserAdministrationViewModel}">
```

This property will return a ViewModel with live services at runtime, and a ViewModel with mock data at design time.

Question:  Will this XAML interfere with what I'm doing in binding a TabItems content to a ViewModel instance, and relying on the dataTemplate above to render the right View?  If so, is there a way to get both of these concepts to work together?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is an easier way to do this. Have a `DesignTimeUserAdministrationViewModel` and populate it with static data in the constructor and refer that in `UserControl` as:

```
<UserControl d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance designTimeVMs:DesignTimeUserAdministrationViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">
```

This way you have a design time test data bound to `d:DataContext` and runtime live data bound to the actual `DataContext`. More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/dd490796(v=vs.100)).

Comment: That looks great.  So if it's design time, that (design time view model) object will be wired up, but at runtime it'll do nothing?

Comment: Yes, it's added for blendability.

Comment: Fantastic! Using `IsDesignTimeCreatable=True` will populate the view with data. If set to `False`, it will only provide the "shape" of the data, which gives full data binding support in the designer, instead of binding blindly. Also, you can use a .xaml file to fully specify example data with `{d:DesignData}`. See [Walkthrough: Using a DesignInstance to Bind to Data in the Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd490796(VS.100).aspx) and [Walkthrough: Using Sample Data in the WPF Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee823176(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: This solution is super!

Comment: Your link is dead - you deleted your WordPress site

Comment: The link to the answer has gone stale, but the MSDN page for a walkthrough of setting up design instance data context for editing XAML markup is explained here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/dd490796(v=vs.100)

Answer (score 1):

Yes I think it will interfere with your current setup

The ViewModelLocator is a static class that returns a dummy object at design time, and a static ViewModel at runtime. This means that

- The ViewModelLocator, not your ParentViewModel, contains your TabViewModels
- You cannot have multiple instances of the same Tab (ViewModel) open at once
- You cannot manage Open/Closed tabs unless you reference the UserControl, which is a violation of the MVVM principle where the ViewModel doesn't know of the View
- You can't instantiate new copies of the TabViewModel with parameterized constructors. For example, `OpenTabs.Add(new CustomerViewModel(CustomerId));`

Perhaps an alternative could be a Converter? One that returns a static object if in design time, or the bound object during runtime? I've never tested such a thing but in theory it should work :)

Answer (score 1):

The built in MS stuff is not bad, but another more elegant and structurally sound alternative which I am busy incorporating in my project is:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn169081.aspx

Basically, you use the MVVM Light toolkit with the SimpleIoc container it comes with and end up with the ability to serve up data for the following three scenarios:

Design time, Run time, and Test time.

Better still, the whole point of MVVM Light is to have your stuff be directly editable in Blend and there is a whole series of videos and blogs and sample apps describing it all. I wish I had found these earlier in my WPF explorations.