# Proper way to use CollectionViewSource in ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, collectionviewsource

I used Drag and Drop to bind Data Source object (a DB model) to `DataGrid` (basically following this example in [Entity Framework Databinding with WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574514).

Everything works fine with this implementation.

### XAML

```
<Window.Resources>    
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="categoryViewSource"  
    d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:Category}, CreateList=True}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource categoryViewSource}">
..
```

### Code Behind

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource categoryViewSource =
      ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("categoryViewSource")));

  _context.Categories.Load();
  categoryViewSource.Source = _context.Categories.Local;        
}
```

### ViewModel

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
}
```

---

However, when I try to use the same code from within ViewModel, it doesn‘t work (`FindResource` is not available), besides, I don’t think this is the right approach (i.e. to use `x:Key` in MVVM).

I would really appreciate any help to point me what is the right way to implement `CollectionViewSource` and `DataBinding` with `DataGrid`.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You have two options to use `CollectionViewSource` properly with MVVM -

1. Expose an `ObservableCollection` of items (`Categories` in your case) through your `ViewModel` and create `CollectionViewSource`  in XAML like this -

   ```
   <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Path=Categories}">
       <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
          <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="CategoryName" />
       </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
   </CollectionViewSource>
   ```

   scm: `xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=Wind‌​owsBase"`

   see this - [`Filtering` collections from XAML using CollectionViewSource](http://www.spikie.be/post/2012/04/12/filtering-collections-from-xaml-using-collectionviewsource.html)
2. Create and Expose an `ICollectionView` directly from your `ViewModel`

   see this - [How to Navigate, Group, Sort and Filter Data in WPF](http://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html)

Following example shows how to create a collection view and
bind it to a `ListBox`

View XAML:

```
<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
    x:Class="CustomerView">
    <ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Customers} />
</Window>
```

View Codebehind:

```
public class CustomerView : Window
{
   public CustomerView()
   {
       DataContext = new CustomerViewModel();
   }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    private readonly ICollectionView customerView;

    public ICollectionView Customers
    {
        get { return customerView; }
    }

    public CustomerViewModel()
    {
        IList<Customer> customers = GetCustomers();
        customerView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView( customers );
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Q. If there is no property to sort on? e.g. if there is an `ObservableCollection` of string or int?

A. In that case you can Simply use **.** as the property name:

```
<scm:SortDescription PropertyName="." />
```

Comment: FYI, `scm:` is this `xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"`

Comment: Hie.. Sorry to be so late with this but even with this solution. how do we then declare the CollectionViewSource in the ViewModel?

Comment: @Offer Hi, I have added the relevant code showing how to declare CollectionViewSource in the ViewModel.

Comment: I have tried this solution, the idea is really great, but I have troubles with getting designtime view to be functional. Maybe you could take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093415/mock-data-not-showing-when-bound-to-icollectionview

Comment: Something is missing here, as the CustomerView class is not referenced.

Comment: @JimBalter I suppose you mean x:Class attribute in xaml code. I might have removed it to keep it short.

Comment: I mean that you define a CustomerView class that is never used. If it's supposed to be referenced from XAML, that's not evident. Complete is far more desirable than short.

Comment: @JimBalter sorry but its just an example, not a full tutorial which spoon feeds everything. It solved OP's problem and that was more desirable at that point of time. Please feel free to update though, that's the beauty of SO.

Comment: What if I have no property to sort on? e.g. if I have observableCollection of strings, or ints or whatever? Instead of custom reference type

Comment: @JohnDemetriou In that case you can Simply use . as the property name:

`<scm:SortDescription PropertyName="." />`

Answer (score 15):

I found that it is handy to have a `CollectionViewSource` in my ViewModel and bind the `ListBox` (in my case) to the `CollectionViewSource.View` while setting the `CollectionViewSource.Source` to be the list I want to use.

Like so:

ViewModel:

```
    public DesignTimeVM()  //I'm using this as a Design Time VM 
    {
        Items = new List<Foo>();
        Items.Add(new Foo() { FooProp= "1", FooPrep= 20.0 });
        Items.Add(new Foo() { FooProp= "2", FooPrep= 30.0 });

        FooViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
        FooViewSource.Source = Items;

        SelectedFoo = Items.First();

        //More code as needed
    }
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FooViewSource.View}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFoo}"/>
```

This means I can do neat stuff in the VM as needed (from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matt/2008/08/28/collectionview-deferrefresh-my-new-best-friend/ ):

```
        using (FooViewSource.DeferRefresh())
        {
            //Remove an old Item
            //add New Item
            //sort list anew, etc. 
        }
```

I suppose this is possible when using the `ICollectionView` object also, but the demo code in the blog link seems to be some codebehind stuff, refering the listbox directly, which I'm trying to avoid.

BTW before you ask, here's how you use a Design Time VM: [WPF Design Time View Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15765986/wpf-design-time-view-model)

Answer (score 4):

Just for reference, another way is to use an attached property on the `CollectionViewSource` which then pipes the functions to the `ViewModel` (Implementing an Interface).

This is a very basic Demonstration just for filtering, it would need some work for e.g. a second Collection on the VM but i think it's enough to show the general technique.

If this is better or worse than the other methods is up for discussion, i just wanted to point out, that there's another way of doing this

Definition of attached Property:

```
public static class CollectionViewSourceFilter
{
    public static IFilterCollectionViewSource GetFilterObject(CollectionViewSource obj)
    {
        return (IFilterCollectionViewSource)obj.GetValue(FilterObjectProperty);
    }

    public static void SetFilterObject(CollectionViewSource obj, IFilterCollectionViewSource value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(FilterObjectProperty, value);
    }

    public static void FilterObjectChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OldValue is IFilterCollectionViewSource oldFilterObject
            && sender is CollectionViewSource oldCvs)
        {
            oldCvs.Filter -= oldFilterObject.Filter;
            oldFilterObject.FilterRefresh -= (s, e2) => oldCvs.View.Refresh();
        }

        if (e.NewValue is IFilterCollectionViewSource filterObject
            && sender is CollectionViewSource cvs)
        {
            cvs.Filter += filterObject.Filter;
            filterObject.FilterRefresh += (s,e2) => cvs.View.Refresh();
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterObjectProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "FilterObject",
        typeof(Interfaces.IFilterCollectionViewSource),
        typeof(CollectionViewSourceFilter),
        new PropertyMetadata(null,FilterObjectChanged)
    );
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IFilterCollectionViewSource
{
    void Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e);
    event EventHandler FilterRefresh;
}
```

usage in xaml:

```
<CollectionViewSource
        x:Key="yourKey"
        Source="{Binding YourCollection}"
        classes:CollectionViewSourceFilter.FilterObject="{Binding}" />
```

and usage in the ViewModel:

```
class YourViewModel : IFilterCollectionViewSource
{
    public event EventHandler FilterRefresh;

    private string _SearchTerm = string.Empty;
    public string SearchTerm
    {
        get { return _SearchTerm; }
        set {
            SetProperty(ref _SearchTerm, value);
            FilterRefresh?.Invoke(this, null);
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<YourItemType> _YourCollection = new ObservableCollection<YourItemType>();
    public ObservableCollection<YourItemType> YourCollection
    {
        get { return _YourCollection; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _YourCollection, value); }
    }

    public void Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Accepted = (e.Item as YourItemType)?.YourProperty?.ToLower().Contains(SearchTerm.ToLower()) ?? true;
    }
}
```