# How to filter DataGrid bound to DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, filter

I'm supposed to add filtering capability to a *DataGrid* that's created and bound as follows.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Things, Mode=TwoWay}" ...>
  ...
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" />
    ...
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

According to [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff407126%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) I'm supposed to add a collection view source and bind to it. However, in the example, they speak of the namespace *local* and I wish to obtain my things from the data context.

```
<Window.Resources>
  <local:Tasks x:Key="tasks" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsTasks" 
                          Source="{StaticResource tasks}" 
                          Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Is it possible? When I've tried that, I get a bunch of empty cells. Clicking on them used to open a dialog where the values of clicked row were editable (and pre-populated with the data in the table) but now I only get empty boxes everywhere. My version looks like this.

```
<Window.Resources>
  <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ThingsFiltered"
                        Source="{Binding Path=Things}"
                        Filter="ThingsFiltered_OnFilter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

And the binding in the data grid is now done like this.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source=ThingsFiltered}" ...>
  ...
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" />
    ...
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

My guess is that I didn't bound the collection view source correctly. IN fact, the method that's supposed to handle the filter doesn't get called at all. After trying different syntaxes both in the data grid and its columns, I admit that I don't know how to make it work. Suggestions?

Comment: Where have you defined "Things"?

Comment: @MaximeTremblay-Savard In my view model. The field *Things* is a part of it and available in the data context (when bound to directly). It's of type *ObservableCollection<SomeThing>*.

Comment: Without having a filter, are you able to fill your datagrid using your *Things*?

Comment: Also, could you post your implementation of *ThingsFiltered_OnFilter* please

Comment: @MaximeTremblay-Savard Yes, before I added the collection view source (binding directly to the view model set to data context in the constructor) it works perfectly. I have *throw new NotImplementedException()* in the handler for the filter but it doesn't get there. That's why I'm asking if it's possible to filter stuff coming in from view model or if the filtering they show is something that can only be done on local resources or something.

Comment: Could you try *e.Accepted = true;* as the implementation instead?

Comment: @MaximeTremblay-Savard Perhaps I was unclear. I have a breakpoint at the start of the method and it doesn't get hit. The exception is not being thrown. It means that the methods doesn't get called to begin with (because I set the collection view source incorrectly, probably). I've added the code suggested by you and, as expected, it didn't get executed (and no difference was to be seen). Can you take a closer look at the creation of my collection view source and bindings made to/from it? Perhaps you'll see something that I'm missing... I'm not using *<local:Tasks x:Key="tasks" />* in my code.

Comment: @MaximeTremblay-Savard I'm trying to follow the first approach [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888619/proper-way-to-use-collectionviewsource-in-viewmodel) but this guy doesn't play around with resources tag for the window at all. And I'm unsure where to put the collection view source tag in my XAML...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you might be having is with the declaration and with your use of the myThings. You need to ensure you define the `local` at the top, and then instanciate your list in the `<Window.Resources>`. When using it in the `Source`of your `<CollectionViewSource>`, ensure you write `StaticResource`before the name, and not `Binding`.

After a lot of testing, here's how i did it. I've used mostly the ideas behind the MSDN documentation.

My MainWindow.xaml. You need to define local to your current solution.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication18.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication18"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Things x:Key="myThings"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ThingsFiltered"
                    Source="{StaticResource myThings}"
                    Filter="ThingsFiltered_OnFilter" />
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ThingsFiltered}}"
      CanUserAddRows="False">
    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

So here, the tricky part about the `<local:Things x:Key="myThings"/>` is that you define your list right there, you then bind to this list.

My other classes are very simple:

```
public class Thing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Things: ObservableCollection<Thing>
{
    public Things()
    {
        this.Add(new Thing() { Id = 1, Name = "Maxime" });
        this.Add(new Thing() { Id = 2, Name = "Konrad" });
    }
}
```

Doing it this way, it finally hits the filter code and does what's intended:

```
private void ThingsFiltered_OnFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    Thing thing = e.Item as Thing;

    if (thing.Name == "Maxime")
    {
        e.Accepted = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Accepted = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Aaaahhh, I just saw it. Forget the *local*. It's that I've skipped *{Static Resource xxx}* in the source definition. It was right there in front of my eyes all the time. Nevertheless, I feel that you've done quite some work, so I'll accept it as an answer (it **did** help, didn't it?) and if you're going for +1 too, I'd like you to state the root cause in the first paragraph of your reply. You might also want to reformat the braces in your code sample (they got off-set a bit), which I feel we should keep for completeness' sake.

Comment: Corrected the braces and added the most common root causes of the issue.