# How to implement a filter box using MVVM in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I'm new to MVVM and WPF and I was wondering if there is a way to implement a search box for a ComboBox using the MVVM pattern. Is there a way to do something like [this post](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/44920/a-reusable-wpf-autocomplete-textbox), not that fancy but a simple ComboBox that allows you to write and filter the items using the MVVM pattern. I've seen a lot of examples here that implements a filter in the code-behind but none doing it in the MVVM way.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that your Combobox items are bound to a collection of some sort as you have mentioned MVVM?

If this is the case, then you could have a look at the CollectionView and CollectionViewSource classes that are part of the System.Windows.Data namespace.

These classes have a Filter property that can be set to return a filtered view of the collection which can be bound to your Combobox.

I have used this in an MVVM app to apply a Filter to a ListView, but the principle should also apply to your Combobox.

Have a look at the official [CollectionView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview(v=vs.110).aspx) and [CollectionViewSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation over at Microsoft for more information.

CollectionViewSource is also discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888619/proper-way-to-use-collectionviewsource-in-viewmodel) StackOverflow thread.