# FilterEventHandler delegate function not firing

Tags: wpf, mvvm, filter, eventhandler, collectionviewsource

New to WPF and MVVM. I'm trying to use a filter with **FilterEventHandler** to a **CollectionViewSource**. I'm trying to add the filter in a property change(**p_sSelectedCreatedDate**). The problem is that **FilterEventHandler** delegate function(**FilterByCreatedDate**) is not firing when I add the filter to the **CollectionViewSource** object. When I debug, I can see in the code that the filter is being added as in the below line.

```
CVS.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(FilterByCreatedDate);
```

However, the code returns without executing **FilterByCreatedDate**.
Note that I am only publishing the code parts which are necessary to this problem and a **BaseViewModel** which inherit from **INotifyPropertyChanged**.

Following is the necessary code.

**ScanBatchWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="BatchManPOC.ScanBatchWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BatchManPOC"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:cmdBehavior="clr-namespace:BatchManPOC.CmdBehavior"
    xmlns:video="clr-namespace:BatchManPOC.Video"
    xmlns:Custom="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="ScanBatchWindow" 
    Height="800"
    Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding p_ListBatches}" x:Key="CVS"/>
</Window.Resources>
     <Grid>
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <Custom:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CVS}}" Margin="8" Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="True"  IsReadOnly="True">
</Custom:DataGrid>
        </Grid>
</Window>
```

**ScanBatchViewModel.cs**

```
public class ScanBatchViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Batch> p_ListBatches { get; set; }
    public CollectionViewSource CVS { get; set; }

    private string _p_sSelectedCreatedDate;
    public string p_sSelectedCreatedDate {
        get
        {
            return _p_sSelectedCreatedDate;
        }
        set
        {
            _p_sSelectedCreatedDate = value;
            ApplyFilter(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_p_sSelectedCreatedDate) ? FilterField.CREATED_DATE : FilterField.NONE);
        }
    }

    public ScanBatchViewModel()
    {
        p_ListBatches = new ObservableCollection<Batch>();

        LoadBatches();
        CVS = new CollectionViewSource();
    }

    private void ApplyFilter(FilterField field)
    {
        switch (field)
        {
            case FilterField.CREATED_DATE:
                AddCreatedDateFilter();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public void AddCreatedDateFilter()
    {
        // see Notes on Adding Filters:
        if (p_bCanRemoveCreatedDateFilter)
        {
            CVS.Filter -= new FilterEventHandler(FilterByCreatedDate);
            CVS.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(FilterByCreatedDate);
        }
        else
        {
            CVS.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(FilterByCreatedDate);
            p_bCanRemoveCreatedDateFilter = true;
        }
    }

    private void FilterByCreatedDate(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        // see Notes on Filter Methods:
        var src = e.Item as Batch;
        if (src == null)
            e.Accepted = false;
        else if (string.Compare(p_sSelectedCreatedDate, src.Date) != 0)
            e.Accepted = false;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`CollectionViewSource.Filter` is an event. It will be fired when the `CollectionViewSource` needs to filter the content. This occurs when the `CollectionViewSource` updates the view.

In order to update the view, call the corresponding method:

```
CVS.View.Refresh();
```

Keep in mind that your method `AddCreatedDateFilter()` could add multiple event handlers for the `Filter` event. Each event handler will be called for each item in the collection. This might cause a performance problem. And all the event handlers are the same, so this is useless too.

So ensure that you only add one event handler for this event.

Comment: Called CVS.View.Refresh();. CVS.View seems to be null and throwing an exception . But I am able to see the populated list in my front-end.

Comment: I was able trigger the filter event FilterByCreatedDate(...) when I set the CVS.Source = p_ListBatches;. Now my problem is, in code where do I have to call the CVS.View.Refresh();. Since I am adding a filter on the property change of 'p_sSelectedCreatedDate', in the code sequence where can I call CVS.View.Refresh();?

Comment: You have two instances of `CollectionViewSource` - the one is in the view created by XAML, the other is in the view-model. That is wrong. You only need one instance of that. Delete the one either in the view-model or in XAML. The `CVS.View.Refresh()` call depends on where `CVS` is stored. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888619/proper-way-to-use-collectionviewsource-in-viewmodel/20899469) for more details. There you can also find an answer showing how to apply a custom filter.