# Binding child nodes to CollectionViewSource

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, collectionviewsource

So here is my data structure:

```
MyViewModel
  Docs (ObservableCollection<Doc>)
    Specs (ObservableCollection<Spec>)
```

i.e. the ViewModel has an `ObservableCollection` named `Docs` that is a collection of `Doc` objects, and in turn each `Doc` object has a collection of `Spec` objects. A property named `position` (available in both Doc and Spec classes) stores the logical position of each doc/spec.

I now need to bind this structure to a `TreeView`. I need to keep both both Docs and Specs sorted at all times (TreeView supports drag-n-drop rearrangement of nodes), so a direct binding cannot work here.

Therefore I use a `CollectionViewSource` to perform sorting at runtime.

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="DocumentsCVS" Source="{Binding Docs}">
  <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    <componentmodel:SortDescription PropertyName="position" />
  </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

and use it in my TreeView:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DocumentsCVS}}">
```

So far so good. The TreeView shows my Docs sorted.

But from here onward things become confusing. How/where do I create `CollectionViewSource` for my specs? I tried doing this in my `HierarchicalDataTemplate`:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
    <Binding>
      <Binding.Source>
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Specs}">
          <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <componentmodel:SortDescription PropertyName="position" />
          </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
      </Binding.Source>
    </Binding>
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

But this doesn't work. Only Docs are listed in the `TreeView`, with no children inside. My gut feeling is that `CollectionViewSource` probably doesn't live in the same `DataContext` as the parent `TreeViewItem`.

Or is this something else?

### Edit

Here is the full XAML of my TreeView:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DocumentsCVS}}" 
           PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High">

  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DocumentVM}">
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
        <Binding>
          <Binding.Source>
            <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Specs}">
          <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <componentmodel:SortDescription PropertyName="position" />
          </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
          </Binding.Source>
        </Binding>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SpecVM}">
          <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <fa:ImageAwesome Grid.Column="0" Icon="PuzzlePiece" Width="16" Margin="3,3,6,3" Foreground="Orange" />
            <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding name}" />
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="FileWordOutline" Height="16" Margin="3,3,6,3" Foreground="Crimson" />
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding name}" />
      </Grid>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Try `Source="{Binding Specs, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"` and see what you see in the VS Output window at runtime. There ought to be a mass of trace information when the binding is attempted to be resolved.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: No luck. It doesn't print out anything in the Output window. And yes, I'm in debug mode.

Comment: That sounds like the Binding never gets resolved. Can I see the whole XAML for the treeview, including the HierarchicalDataTemplates?

Comment: @EdPlunkett: See my edit please.

Comment: Is that what you did with `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High"`, put it on the TreeView rather than on the Binding to `Specs`, as suggested?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be what happened. You'd have found that there was no "framework mentor" -- the Binding didn't know to go look for a DataContext. I've kicked this around a bit. I can't find a place to define the CollectionViewSource where it inherits the DataContext from the template. I think [this is your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20899469/424129) (option 2, ICollectionView).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Specs}">
```

The Binding on Source there doesn't know where to go look for a DataContext (no "framework mentor"). I've kicked this around a bit. I can't find a place to define the CollectionViewSource where it inherits the DataContext from the template.

I did find a solution.

C#

```
public class SortConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(value);
        view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription((string)parameter, ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        return view;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate 
    DataType="{x:Type vm:DocumentVM}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Specs, Converter={StaticResource SortConverter}, ConverterParameter=position}"
    >
```

This could be made more useful by giving the converter multiple PropertyName/SortDirection properties, or a collection of SortDescriptions. You could make it a MarkupExtension. You could also just create the collection view in a viewmodel property.

Comment: Thank you very much. That got me headed in the right direction. I didn't succeed on the `MarkupExtension` path, so I reverted back to using converter. After spending a few hours with it, I finally got it working. Thing is that you have to cast the view to `ICollectionViewLiveShaping` and enable live sorting on it before returning it from the converter; else it won't reorder tree nodes automatically.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll add that to the answer when I get home (or feel free to edit it if you’re incline)