# How to use d:DesignInstance with types that don't have default constructor?

Tags: .net, xaml, data-binding

I am binding a textbox to an object, like so:

```
  <TextBlock d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance ViewModel:TaskVM }" 
             Text="{Binding Title}" MouseLeftButtonDown="TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown">
  </TextBlock>
```

Now I am wondering how to make it display mock data during design. I've tried doing something like that:

```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" MouseLeftButtonDown="TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <d:DesignProperties.DataContext>
       <ViewModel:TaskVM Title="Mock"/>
    </d:DesignProperties.DataContext>
  </TextBlock>
```

However, since TaskVM has no default ctor, I am getting a "No default constructor" found.

I know that when I use `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance ViewModel:TaskVM }"` it creates a mock data type. Is there a way for me to set the properties of this mock type?

Thanks!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The default constructor is required for a type to be instantiated in XAML. As a workaround you can simply create a subclass of `TaskVM` that will have the default contructor and use it as a design time data context.

```
<TextBlock d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance ViewModel:DesignTimeTaskVM }" 
           Text="{Binding Title}" MouseLeftButtonDown="TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown">
</TextBlock>
```

Another alternative is to set `d:IsDesignTimeCreatable` to `False` and a substitute type will be created for you at runtime (using your TaskVM type as a "shape").

```
<TextBlock d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance ViewModel:DesignTimeTaskVM, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}" 
           Text="{Binding Title}" MouseLeftButtonDown="TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown">
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: I like that idea :). Inheriting will allow me to skip the re-creating of all the properties. I'd still prefer there was a built-in way to manipulate the mock object that WPF creates. It DOES create a mock object, doesn't it? It says in MSDN documentation: d:IsDesignTimeCreatable
 

In the d:DesignInstance markup extension, specifies that the design instance is created from your type, instead of a designer-generated substitute type.

Comment: @VitalyB - Yes, you are right. It looks like you can set `d:IsDesignTimeCreatable` to `False` and a substitute type will be created for you at runtime (using your TaskVM type as a "shape").

Comment: Exactly. Which is rather daunting that I can't set properties of that substitute type.

Answer (score 9):

Another alternative would be to use a static class to hold the view model and call that class from the XAML.
Here is an example:

The xaml uses a view model factory to create the design data context:

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DataContext="{x:Static local:ViewModelFactory.ViewModel}"
```

The static ViewModelFactory constructs the view model in its constructor and stores it in a public property where it can be accessed from outside (from the XAML):

```
public static class ViewModelFactory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Static constructor.
    /// </summary>
    static ViewModelFactory()
    {
        ViewModel = new TypeOfViewModel(null);

        // further configuration of ViewModel
    }

    public static TypeOfViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

Please note that the `TypeOfViewModel` class has no parameterless constructor.
So the ViewModelFactory has to pass some value, in this case `null`.

So in this scenario the `TypeOfViewModel` class would need to be implemented in a way that it is aware that during design time the passed in dependency is null.

```
public class TypeOfViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dependency">May be null at design time</param>
    public TypeOfViewModel(SomeDependentClass dependency)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You could add a default constructor to your VM. It could then check if it is in design time and set appropriate design-time values for its properties.

Comment: Another option is to create a default constructor and mark it with  
`[Obsolete("use only for design mode", True)]`  
so it raises a compile error if you try to use it.

Comment: Link is dead. Refers to this question instead: https://stackoverflow.com/q/834283/200443