# Generate compile-time error for a particular constructor overload invocation

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to generate a compile-time warning/error if a particular overload of the constructor is accessed anywhere in entire solution?

## Detail

This is a WPF desktop (.NET 7) project. My Pages and UserControls use `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:UnderlyingVM}"` feature to take advantage of design-time intellisense. However, the underlying VMs require passing in external services (standard IoC/DI stuff) in their constructors, while the designer can invoke parameter-less constructors only.

To get around this problem, I have defined parameter-less constructor overloads in each VM. Sole purpose and usage of these overloads is the designer support and these overloads must not inadvertently be called from anywhere else. Is there a way to generate a compile-time warning/error if such an invocation is found anywhere in the regular code?

One approach that I thought of was use the following in the parameter-less constructor:

```
if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()))
{
  #error ("This constructor can only be invoked from the WPF designer.");
}
```

Unfortunately, the VM layer is a .NET Standard 2.0 project and therefore cannot reference .NET 6/7 assemblies. Can anyone suggest an alternate approach?

Comment: You could try with the [Obsolete] attribute

Comment: @SomeBody: This indeed is a clean solution and can be used to report it both as a warning or error (compile-time). Any idea why this error is not thrown when used in XAML?

Comment: XAML uses reflection. When you use reflection, the compiler doesn't have a chance to spot that there's an Obsolete attribute at compile-time

Comment: @canton7: Hmm.. Thanks for the input. So attributes do not end up in the compiled assemblies? Or is it only the `Obsolete` attribute that works this way?

Comment: @SomeBody. BTW, feel free to post it as answer. I'll happily accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: They do, but you can't get a compiler error when using reflection at runtime. The reflection mechanism doesn't care about checking for Obsolete attributes either (and all it would be able to do is to throw an exception at runtime)

Comment: You could add `d:IsDesignTimeCreatable=False` to XAML and remove the default c'tor again, see also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472228/how-to-use-ddesigninstance-with-types-that-dont-have-default-constructor

Comment: @KlausGütter: Thanks for sharing. That is a great post and discusses many of the ideas shared on this page. Wish I'd found it earlier. One thing though. Setting `d:IsDesignTimeCreatable=False` may or may not be feasible depending upon whether you want the designer-generated instance of the VM to perform any initialization actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`ObsoleteAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.obsoleteattribute?view=net-7.0):

```
public class Example
{
   [Obsolete("this constructor should only be used by the WPF designer")]
   public Example()
   {
   }
}
```

By default, if you call a method with this attribute, you will get a compiler warning.

Comment: You can set `IsError = true` or pass `true` to the ctor to get an error rather than a warning