# VS 2012 hangs on loading XAML designer

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012

We do MVVM and use DI in our WPF project. Now we are working on VS 2012. Whenever we open the views (XAML forms) the XAML designer shows the loading message. Then whenever we try to change the XAML code panel VS hangs (While it is froze on loading message). XDesProc.exe takes about 13% of CPU (As I have 8 cores so it takes 100% of a core). When I close it, VS goes out of halt. But if you change the XAML code the scenario will be repeated again.

We didn't have any problem with VS 2010 in the same situation.

What is wrong?

Comment: I know obvious by you did try Build / Clean Solution?

Comment: The WPF designer was heavily modified in VS2012 and was one of the last components that stabilized in the beta.  It sure looks like it has some residual trouble (aka latent bugs).  You can create a feedback article at connect.microsoft.com, they'll need a repro project so they can debug it.  Use Microsoft Support if you can't wait.

Comment: Does it also happen in the latest version of Blend?

Comment: I see this pretty often. The XAML designer is quite flakey. Not sure if it's just because I have Resharper installed or not. I have had to also kill XDesProc.exe on numerous ocassions because it locks up my system. I have 8 cores, and 16GB of RAM on an SSD... I doubt that hardware is an issue...

Comment: Issue is still there in VS 2012 Ultimate Update 3.

Comment: The issue still exists in VS 2013.

Answer (score 2):

A work-around is described in this thread:

[Visual Studio 2012 hangs on editing XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442527/visual-studio-2012-hangs-on-editing-xaml)

To summarise you can make VS not use the XAML designer, and just use the regular source editor:

1. Right-click on a XAML file in the Solution Explorer
2. Select "Open With..."
3. Select "Source Code (Text) Editor"
4. Click on "Set as Default"
5. Click OK
6. You're done!

Comment: The OP is asking how to open the XAML **Designer** not a text view so this is hardly a solution.

Comment: I've hit the same issue, been enormously frustrated by it and this is the best way I've found to work around it. A work around is better than no solution at all.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue on one of my views. It is not really a solution but i noticed that, when I comment out the DataContext Property, the cpu load is gone.

1. Open Xaml file (cpu load is rising)
2. Comment out DataContext property with viewmodel binding
3. Kill XDescProc.exe in TaskManager
4. Reload Designer (no cpu load)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the latest update to Visual Studio [Update 1](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/visual-studio-update). If after the update it still occurs submit the issue to [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you that, if you have any code in the constructor or any other code that might execute in the designer, you detect the design mode and do not execute that code.

You might be connecting to a data source and the designer might be choking on that.

See: [Is there a way to check if WPF is currently executing in design mode or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834283/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-wpf-is-currently-executing-in-design-mode-or-not)

Answer (score 0):

Our computer's VS2012 has updated to Update 4, but it is still hangs on loading XAML designer..