# Visual Studio 2015 designer crash

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I have this method:

```
static public void WriteErrorToFile(string ErrorMassege, string HelpLink)
{
    string text = DateTime.Now.ToString() + ":" + Environment.NewLine + ErrorMassege + Environment.NewLine;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HelpLink))
    {
        text += "Help link: " + HelpLink + Environment.NewLine;
    }

    text += Environment.NewLine;
    File.AppendAllText("errors.txt", text);
}
```

I call this method every time some expception occurred, but then the designer in Visual Studio 2015 crashes with massege:

> UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\errors.txt' is denied.

If that mean something to you I call this function in MyViewModel what is datacontext of my page. If I delete `errors.txt` file then everything is normal again. Anyone knows why this happen and what is the soulution?

Comment: The easier is probably to distinct [design time](http://stackoverflow.com/q/834283/1997232) and don't do anything what may crash designer. Also, during debugging you shouldn't handle everything, check for [debugger presence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached(v=vs.110).aspx) and e.g. don't handle unhandled exceptions in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that the WPF designer has to execute your code to see what data is available to it on the viewModel the [DesignerProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerproperties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) contains a method GetIsInDesignMode that you can use to disable logic when your code is being executed by the designer