# How can I specify certain XAML elements should only display in Design Mode?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there some special XML tag or property I can add to my XAML to make certain child elements on a `UserControl` only appear in Design Mode? Something like this?

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid>
        <IfDesignMode>
            <Show-This-Element-Only-In-Design-Mode />
        </IfDesignMode>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: May be [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834283/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-wpf-is-currently-executing-in-design-mode-or-not) can help you

Answer (score 0):

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
public SomeViewModel()
{    
if(Execute.InDesignMode)
{
    //write some code here
    UIelementName.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden
}}
```

for further help visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834283/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-wpf-is-currently-executing-in-design-mode-or-not) for more help

Comment: That only applies if you're using Caliburn.Micro

Comment: yes it can only be used if Caliburn.Micro is being used. but thats one of the easiest ways of doing it.

Comment: Adding a whole new dependency to a project for something as minor as this does not seem like a sensible way to go, especially when there are other (native) ways of doing it like other answers on your link suggest.

Comment: You can use `DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this);` to find out whether or not you're executing in design mode. This requires no dependencies.