# Display design time element instead of run time respective element

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, designtime-attributes

I am using design time namespace to use design time properties and elements. I use

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
```

Now, I need to define design time element, let's say

```
<d:TextBlock Text="design time text block" />
```

But in runtime, I want to display other text block:

```
<TextBlock Text="runtime text block" />
```

How to define both elements, so design time elemnt is displayed **instead** of respective run time element?

The way I fiugred out is:

```
<Grid>
    <d:TextBlock Text="design time text block" />
    <TextBlock Text="runtime text block" />
</Grid>
```

But I don't want to define extra container. I could also use <d:Grid>`, but it justs omits whole grid together with text block in runtime.

I know I can use `d:Text` design time property, but in real situation I need to set attached property on element, whcih already has its own namespace, eg. `ns:AttachedProp` and I cannot use two namespaces like `d:ns:AttachedProp`.

Comment: @MickyD I see what you mean, but the control itself is custom button control, so it would not work.

Comment: ah I see.  No problem good sir

Comment: I wasn't aware you can use design-only elements. But you can easily [check for design mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/834283/1997232) in logic of attached behavior or somewhere else.

Comment: Are you wanting design time controls rather than design time data? I'm not sure what that gains you over design time data and databinding.

Comment: Something like that? Or is it more complicated?
<TextBlock Tag="True" d:Tag="{x:Null}" AttachedProperty="{Binding Tag,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"></TextBlock>

Comment: Perhaps, you need not attribute-property, but element-property?

Comment: I have always used `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:ViewModel}"` to deal with these instances. However I don't know how this works with attached props. There is also a way for you to generate this data based on vm through Blend.