# Different position between designer view and compiled build

Tags: c#, wpf

In my first attempts to work with WPF I encountered a problem where coordinates that I choose in designer's view for buttons are different in what I see when I compile my program. Here's how it looks like:

[image]

[image]

Buttons are a little bit lower (cropped) in compiled version. Any ideas on what is happening here?

Code:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="Player.MainWindow"
        Title="Player" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" StateChanged="Window_StateChanged" Icon="Resources/radio.ico" WindowStartupLocation="Manual" Closing="Window_Closing" Left="0" d:DesignWidth="448" d:DesignHeight="110" Width="448" Height="110">
    <Grid Margin="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="nextButton" Content="Next" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,38,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="45" Click="nextButton_Click" Height="22"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="prevButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="209" IsEnabled="False" TextAlignment="Center"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: It looks the same to me... are you sure you aren't just experiencing an optical illusion?

For example, which circle is bigger: http://ankeshkothari.com/illusions/size-illusion.png

Comment: But do you see that in the first image buttons are not cropped, while in the second picture they are?

Comment: @martynaspikunas Have you taken the window border into account?

Comment: @martynaspikunas: Sorry, I thought you cropped the picture out on purpose because you meant that the buttons are not accurate in relation to the textbox. Might I suggest you post the code, otherwise it is too difficult to answer this question.

Comment: @grizzly, no. But the thing is that when you work with WFA, you see buttons and other elements in the same position while looking at designer's view and compiled version. I am trying to achieve something similar with WPF.

Comment: @m-y, sorry. My bad. I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @martynaspikunas As m-y has mentioned, post the XAML code please. There might be another catch.

Comment: @martynaspikunas Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831573/why-is-a-window-larger-in-runtime

Comment: @grizzly, it works. Thanks! If you want to get some points for your help, please edit your previous answer to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opened up GIMP and put your images on top of each other, with the top of having 50% transparency and this is the result:

[image]

And voila - the XAML designer and the compiled output **is identical**. I would even assume that VS designer displays some sort of background-compiled version of your XAML to achieve this high-fidelity representation.

Back to your edited question: according to this question: [Why is a window larger in runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831573/why-is-a-window-larger-in-runtime) you need to set the width/height on the `Grid` and set the `SizeToContent` attribute of the `Window` to `WidthAndHeight`.

Here is an updated version of your code:

```
<Window (...)
    SizeToContent='WidthAndHeight'>
        <Grid
            Height='110'
            Width='448'
            Margin="0">
(...)
```

And the result is:
[image]