# Silverlight AutoSize and Visual Studio 2010 for Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, expression-blend, windows-phone-7.1

I have designer using Blend to desing windows phone pages. It has d:DesignHeight and d:DesignWidth set.

I use Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone. Now if I open any .xaml file in DesignMode, it reset the DesignHeight and Width. It is really annoying as I have to manually change back those values before checking in my changes to sourceControl.

Saw this one [WPF UserControl Design Time Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75495/wpf-usercontrol-design-time-size)
but to do it in every page would be a stupidity for me.

Hope there is a switch in VS, which I am not aware of.

Any ideas please?

**Update**
I have the following:

```
SupportedOrientations="Landscape"  Orientation="Landscape" 
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="480">
```

When I view in Design Mode it changes to

```
d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="782">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Phone has a fixed Page size (480x800 pixels)

When you design a Page the designer determines the appropriate size in the designer by looking at the orientation of the page and the visibility of the SystemTray:

```
SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False">
```

My guess is that because you can only design Pages that are full screen, the designer keeps replacing custom set values for the height and width.

When creating a User Control (not a Page!) you are free to change the Height and Width any way you want.

Comment: Check my updated question. From your explanation, I think because my Landscape mode it is causing that. But then in that case the designer should be seeing that as well right? I will try few thing based on your explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is the intended behavior to enable you to design/see the page in the designer in both orientations.